# updating CLOB column with multiple namespace in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to update an element which is inside a clob column in oracle DB.

First challenge I am facing is that my clob xml has 2 namespaces and I am not able to get that working .

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<esbmsg:EsbMessage xmlns:esbmsg="http://www.test.com/esb/message/1.0">
  <esbmsg:Body>
    <Transaction xmlns="http://test.com">
      <test-element>
        <finalElement>false</finalElement>
      </test-elemen>
    </Transaction>
  </esbmsg:Body>
</esbmsg:EsbMessage>



select x.* from cc_messagehistory y
cross join xmltable(
  xmlnamespaces('http://www.test.com/esb/message/1.0' as "esbmsg",
    'http://test.com ' ),
  '/esbmsg:EsbMessage'
  passing xmltype.createxml(y.payload)  
    factext varchar2(10) path '/esbmsg:EsbMessage/esbmsg:Body/Transaction/test-element/finalElement'
) x;
```

> ORA-19102: XQuery string literal expected
>   19102. 00000 -  "XQuery string literal expected"
>   *Cause:    The string literal containing the XQuery expression was missing.
>   *Action:   Specify the XQuery expression as a string literal. Error at Line: 64 Column: 99

Comment: Please edit the question and post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The immediate cause of the ORA-01902 is that you missed the `default` keyword:

```
  xmlnamespaces('http://www.test.com/esb/message/1.0' as "esbmsg",
    default 'http://test.com'),
```

I've removed the extra space at the end of the URI, which would cause problems later. But you are also missing the `columns` keyword, and you can simplify the conversion of the CLOB value to an XMLType.

Putting that together, and with a CTE to supply your (corrected) sample XML:

```
-- CTE for sample data
with cc_messagehistory(payload) as (
select to_clob('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<esbmsg:EsbMessage xmlns:esbmsg="http://www.test.com/esb/message/1.0">
  <esbmsg:Body>
    <Transaction xmlns="http://test.com">
      <test-element>
        <finalElement>false</finalElement>
      </test-element>
    </Transaction>
  </esbmsg:Body>
</esbmsg:EsbMessage>') from dual
)
-- actual query
select x.*
from cc_messagehistory y
cross join xmltable (
  xmlnamespaces (
    'http://www.test.com/esb/message/1.0' as "esbmsg",
    default 'http://test.com'
  ),
  '/esbmsg:EsbMessage'
  passing xmltype(y.payload)  
  columns factext varchar2(10)
  path '/esbmsg:EsbMessage/esbmsg:Body/Transaction/test-element/finalElement'
) x;

FACTEXT   
----------
false
```

---

For the update you could do something like:

```
update cc_messagehistory y
set payload = XMLSerialize(document
  XMLQuery('declare default element namespace "http://test.com"; (: :)
    declare namespace esbmsg="http://www.test.com/esb/message/1.0"; (: :)
    copy $i := $xml modify (
      for $j in $i//esbmsg:EsbMessage/esbmsg:Body/Transaction/test-element/finalElement
      return replace value of node $j with $new
    )
    return $i'
    passing xmltype(y.payload) as "xml",
    'true' AS "new"
    returning content
  )
  indent size=2
)
where xmlexists('declare default element namespace "http://test.com"; (: :)
  declare namespace esbmsg="http://www.test.com/esb/message/1.0"; (: :)
  $xml//esbmsg:EsbMessage/esbmsg:Body/Transaction/test-element/finalElement[text()="false"]'
  passing xmltype(y.payload) as "xml");
```

which transforms that source CLOB into:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<esbmsg:EsbMessage xmlns:esbmsg="http://www.test.com/esb/message/1.0">
  <esbmsg:Body>
    <Transaction xmlns="http://test.com">
      <test-element>
        <finalElement>true</finalElement>
      </test-element>
    </Transaction>
  </esbmsg:Body>
</esbmsg:EsbMessage>
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=61f4e5a594c502da2f4c7cfedad98406) (works on 18c; errors on 11gR2, but patch levels may make a difference; also tested successfully elsewhere on 12cR1)